# Runtime error alongside Django on Amazon AWS EC2 Linux AMI issue

Tags: python, linux, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am getting this error: signalling support is unavailable because the blinker library is not installed.

I am running Django 1.6.5 under python 2.6.9.

Is it possible that the error will go away if i update python on the server to 2.7.x?

If so how can I update the server without losing everything I have done upto this point creating my website on the instance?

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just install blinker by typing `pip install blinker` in the console.

Be sure you install it in your virtualenv if by any chance you use one, just by activating it before executing the pip command.

You may also review your staging procedure to correctly install project dependencies.